# Google+ Sign Up with Devise and Rails (google_oauth2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, google-plus, omniauth

I'm getting the following error when trying to sign in through google+ using the google_oauth2 gem.

```
undefined method `find_for_google_oauth2' for #<Class:0x007ff70a337148>
```

Here's the three files I've altered for sign up.

user.rb

```
def google_oauth2
  user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])
  if user.persisted?
    flash.notice = "Signed in Through Google!"
    sign_in_and_redirect user
  else
    session["devise.user_attributes"] = user.attributes
    flash.notice = "You are almost Done! Please provide a password to finish setting up your account"
    redirect_to new_user_registration_url
  end
end
```

omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb

```
def google_oauth2
  # You need to implement the method below in your model (e.g. app/models/user.rb)
  @user = User.find_for_google_oauth2(request.env["omniauth.auth"], current_user)

  if @user.persisted?
    flash[:notice] = I18n.t "devise.omniauth_callbacks.success", :kind => "Google"
    sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication
  else
    session["devise.google_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
    redirect_to new_user_registration_url
  end
end
```

and I've added config.omniauth :google_oauth2 in my devise.rb file.

routes.rb

```
 devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => "registrations", :sessions => "sessions", :omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks" }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `find_for_google_oauth2` from the `omniauth_callbacks_controller`, but you are using the wrong method name `google_oauth2`. You should replace `google_oauth2` with `find_for_google_oauth2`.

And it seems like the code in `user.rb` is incorrect because it contains the controller code. Do you see it looks exactly the same like your controller code? :)

Correct code for user.rb

```
def self.find_for_google_oauth2(access_token, signed_in_resource=nil)
    data = access_token.info
    user = User.where(:email => data["email"]).first

    # Uncomment the section below if you want users to be created if they don't exist
    # unless user
    #     user = User.create(name: data["name"],
    #        email: data["email"],
    #        password: Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
    #     )
    # end
    user
end
```

Read more here: https://github.com/zquestz/omniauth-google-oauth2#devise